# What is the mistake when I write down the class equation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite group with $n$ elements which has a trivial center.
If we consider $G=\{e, x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n-1} \}$, then from the class equation we have that $$n=1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} [G:C(x_k)].\tag{1}$$
By Lagrange's theorem we have that $n=|C(x_k)|\cdot [G:C(x_k)], \forall k=\overline{1,n-1}$, so $(1)$ rewrites as $$n=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n}{|C(x_k)|}.\tag{2}$$
If we let $M=\max\{|C(x_k)| | k=\overline{1,n-1}\}$(this is possible since these sets are finitee), we have that $\frac{n}{|C(x_k)|}\ge  \frac{n}{M}$, so $(2)$ implies that $$n-1\ge \frac{n(n-1)}{M}\iff M\ge n\tag{3}$$
and since $M\le n$, we obtain that $M=n$, which contradicts the fact that $Z(G)=\{e\}$.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have $n-1$ distinct conjugacy classes(why?). Thus, you cannot take the sum from $1$ to $n-1$ in Equation $(1)$.

Comment: I thought that this might be the case, but I don't know why. My reasoning was that all the elements which are not part of $Z(G)$ have a non-trivial orbit. Could you tell me how to determine the actual number of distinct conjugacy classes?

Comment: @user69503 I don't know if it's possible to determine the exact number of conjugacy classes. Your reasoning is correct though. A conjugacy class is a singleton set $\{x\} $ iff $x\in Z(G)$. If there were  $n-1$ conjugacy classes, then....

Comment: Thank you, in my textbook they just say that $|G|=|Z(G)|+ \sum\limits_{Gx \text{non-trivial orbit}} [G:C(x)]$ and this is where my error stemmed from.