# Does a centerless finite group whose cardinality is not divisible by $4$ have this property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a centerless group (i.e. $Z(G)=\{e\}$) with $n$ elements, where $n$ is an integer which is not divisible by $4$. Is it true then that $\exists a,b \in G$, $a\ne b$ such that $C(a)=C(b)$?

I tried to use the class equation, but I wrote it wrongly and as a result I made no progress. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537006/what-is-the-mistake-when-i-write-down-the-class-equation) is basically what I tried to do and it is definitely wrong.

I don't really know what else to try. I thought about assuming the contrary and trying to reach a contradiction, but I got stuck really quick.

Comment: Is $C(a)$ the centralizer of $a$, or is it the conjugacy class of $a$?

Comment: $a$ and $a^{-1}$ always have the same centralizer, and there is definitely an element that's not equal to its own inverse since $G$ is centerless

Comment: @math54321: That was my thought as well, but then the fact that $|G|$ is not divisible by $4$ is irrelevant ($G$ cannot be a $p$-group and cannot be abelian, so $|G|$ is divisible by an odd prime). That's why I *think* it means conjugacy class instead of centralizer.

Comment: It means centralizer, sorry for not stating it clearly.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I also suspected that the hypothesis about $n$ may be useless, this is basically a result I would like to use in a different problem. Since I wasn't sure whether that part is useful here, I decided to add it, but I now realize that I should have stated this in my post.

Comment: It is true in any nontrivial group $G$ that there exist $a,b \in G$, $a \neq b$ such that $C_G(a) = C_G(b)$.

Answer (score 4):

Given that $C(a)$ means "centralizer of $a$ [in $G$]":

Since $G$ is centerless, it is either trivial or nonabelian. If it is trivial, you have no hope, so I guess it's supposed to be non-trivial. The order cannot be a prime power, so $|G|$ must be divisible by an odd prime $p$. Let $a$ be an element of order $p$. Let $b=a^{-1}$.

Note that the hypothesis on $|G|$ is irrelevant: if $G$ is centerless, it cannot be a nontrivial $p$-group, so you know for sure $|G|$ is either $1$ or divisible by an odd prime, and the result follows.

But the result also follows for non-centerless groups: if $Z(G)$ is nontrivial, pick $g\in Z(G)$, $g\neq e$; then $C(g)=C(e)=G$. A better question then would be whether you can find such elements with $C(a)=C(b)\neq G$.

The only obstacle to the same answer would be if for every $g\in G$, either $g\in Z(G)$ or $g=g^{-1}$. I claim that this is impossible.

Indeed, if you had such a group $G$, then $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, so $G$ is nilpotent of class $2$ and is the product of its $p$-parts. The odd $p$ parts are all abelian, so we are reduced to a $2$-group of class exactly $2$ with every noncentral element of order $2$. Let $x$ be noncentral and $y$ be an element of $G$ that does not commute with $x$. Then $\langle x,y\rangle$ is a nonabelian group of class $2$, generated by two elements of order $2$. The only possibility is that it is the dihedral group of order $8$, but that group has a noncentral element of order $4$, and hence that element would be noncentral in $G$ of order $4$, a contradiction. So if $G$ is not abelian, then you can always find an $a$, $a\neq a^{-1}$ with $C(a)\neq G$.

Comment: If $a \neq a^{-1}$ for some $a \in G$, then pick $b = a^{-1}$. The other possibility is that $a = a^{-1}$ for all $a \in G$, in which case $G$ is abelian and so $C_G(a) = C_G(b) = G$ for any $a,b \in G$.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: But one might want $C(a)=C(b)\neq G$ (when $G$ is not abelian).

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: And such an element always exists if $G$ is not abelian, though I don't think it is trivial. I've added a proof.

Comment: Here is another proof of that. If $a \neq a^{-1}$ for some $a \not\in Z(G)$ we are done. Otherwise, we have that $a^2 \neq 1$ implies $a \in Z(G)$. I claim that this implies that $G$ is abelian. Clearly $xy = yx$ if $x$ or $y$ is central. An easy exercise shows that $xy = yx$ if $xy$ is central. So we may assume $x, y, xy \not\in Z(G)$, but then $x^2 = y^2 = (xy)^2 = 1$, in which case $xy = yx$ by another common exercise.